# Lightweight node: Can I prune the chain on my node?

Tags: nodeos, irreversible, single-node

I am aware of the option `--validation-mode=light` when starting `nodeos`to have the node skip the verification of the transaction in each block, making the sync faster, and the CPU requirements for the node lower.

However, I would like to have the blocks pruned, keeping only the latest irreversible block on disk so I could run a validation node in a lower specs machine.

How can I delete the blocks of the chain keeping only the most recent blocks?

Is there an option to start `nodeos`for that? (`--help` does not say anything about that).

Should I delete the blocks.bin and leave the forkdb file only?

Answer (score 1):

I would look into EOS Rio's **Hyperion** Solution for producing a light full history node.  This could help achieve your goal of reducing the node's storage requirements as well as decreasing the syncing time.

From their announcement:

> Changing format and cutting data redundancies reduces database size in
>   about **85%**, from almost 5 Tb to approximately 650 Gb. To further
>   improve performance we engineered a multi-threaded indexer that
>   extracts data from the state history plugin and makes it possible to
>   ingest the complete EOS blockchain in approximately **72 hours** with
>   proper hardware optimization, while the current solutions can take
>   weeks.

https://medium.com/@eosriobrazil/presenting-hyperion-history-api-solution-f8a8fda5865b

https://eosrio.io/hyperion/

https://t.me/eosrio