# Can I truncate blocks.log file

Tags: log

I want to build a small blockchain based on EOSIO and I want to conserve disk space on some nodes.

I don't need full history on the light nodes, just the current state of the blockchain which is in RAM. Can I delete the blocks.log file from time to time on a regular basis to free up disk space on my light node to make it lighter? Is there any recommended way or RPC call to do this?

Does this limit the ability of the node in anyway? I know it won't be able to transmit old blocks to other nodes that need to sync but I don't care for that as there will be other nodes with the full blocks.log file. Is there any other use to the blocks.log file in the EOSIO software?

Possible duplicate of [this unanswered question](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/4000/lightweight-node-can-i-prune-the-chain-on-my-node)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like there's an executable called [blocklogtrim](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/blob/blockLogTrim/programs/blockLogTrim/blockLogTrim.cpp) in the makes that let's you truncate block.log files.

- No official support and not merged into master but maybe worth a look.

Comment: Thanks for the find, looks spot on, I will dig into that!

Answer (score 0):

I would look into EOS Rio's **Hyperion** Solution for producing a light full history node.  This could help achieve your goal of reducing the node's storage requirements.

From their announcement:

> Changing format and cutting data redundancies reduces database size in
>   about **85%**, from almost 5 Tb to approximately 650 Gb. To further
>   improve performance we engineered a multi-threaded indexer that
>   extracts data from the state history plugin and makes it possible to
>   ingest the complete EOS blockchain in approximately **72 hours** with
>   proper hardware optimization, while the current solutions can take
>   weeks.

https://medium.com/@eosriobrazil/presenting-hyperion-history-api-solution-f8a8fda5865b

https://eosrio.io/hyperion/

https://t.me/eosrio

Comment: This is interesting but I want something more extreme - no history at all in my lightweight node, throw it out the window. Keep just the current state in RAM. Is that possible?